# DirectoryEntry CommitChanges returns Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation on server 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, directory, active-directory

I tried to create reset password and user creation functions for Active Directory. On my PC with below code is works just fine without any error. But when I publish to the server, I received error: **Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation**.

```
ADResult hasil = new ADResult();
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(_path, _adminID, _adminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
string query = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", user.userID);

ds.Filter = query;
ds.Sort.PropertyName = "CN";
ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
ds.CacheResults = false;

try
{
 SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
 if (sr == null)
 {
  hasil.errorCode = -1;
  hasil.result = "User name not found in this domain.";
 }
 else
 {
  DirectoryEntry userCredentials = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
  userCredentials.Invoke("SetPassword", new Object[] { user.password });
  userCredentials.CommitChanges();
  userCredentials.Close();
  hasil.errorCode = 0;
  hasil.result = "Password for " + user.userID + " changed successfully.";
 }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 hasil.errorCode = -1;
 hasil.result = e.Message + "<br/>" + e.StackTrace + "<br/>" + e.Source;
}
return hasil;
```

Is there something configuration/settings that I missed on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code using

> UserPrincipal

instead of

> DirectoryEntry

and it works perfectly.
I use this code:

```
PrincipalContext PrincipalContext4 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "full_domain_name.com", "OU=User_OU,DC=domain_name,DC=co,DC=id", _adminID, _adminPassword);
UserPrincipal UserPrincipal1 = new UserPrincipal(PrincipalContext4, user.userID, user.password, true);

//User Logon Name
UserPrincipal1.UserPrincipalName = user.userID;
UserPrincipal1.Name = user.firstName + " " + user.lastName;
UserPrincipal1.GivenName = user.firstName;
UserPrincipal1.Surname = user.lastName;
UserPrincipal1.DisplayName = user.firstName + " " + user.lastName;
UserPrincipal1.Enabled = true;
UserPrincipal1.Save();
```

I still don't know why I use DirectoryEntry is not working on windows server 2019

Answer (score 0):

That't not the exact error message,real error must be wrapped.You can write loggers or event logging after lines which you think could be culprit.You can check event log on that server if you can find elaborated stack Trace. You can check that user have admin privilege for that server to lookup in AD.

Comment: the error always stop on CommitChanges: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)\r\n at TAM.ActiveDirectory.Controllers.UserController.ResetPassword(ADUser user). Or for reset AD password I cannot invoke "SetPassword"?

Comment: it works on my PC as AD client, but when I upload to the server, I received that error

Comment: I agree, you need to find a better error message. Look at the [`InnerException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=netframework-4.8) property of the exception. And then look at the `InnerException` of that. Continue until you see the exception that has no `InnerException`.

Comment: Or just call `ToString()` on the exception and it will show you all the inner exceptions with all of their stack traces.

Comment: Is you pc connected to the same domain, as the production server? There may be group policy password restriction (length, complexity). To verify that your password meets the requirements, you need to log in under the admin user, open ADUC on the production server and try to reset user’s password to the same value

Comment: @oldovets yes, the development PC is already on the same domain as the production server. The password I'm trying to use is the same as I tried on the dev and prod. so basically I have submitted with the same value, but different location (dev windows 10 pro, prod windows server 2019)

Comment: @Zakki If you still want to figure out why you got the exception, you need to look at the inner exception messages as I described above.